# why are some bootstrap classes aren't working in my react project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm testing boostrap 5 alpha with npm here's how it looked like in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-scrollspy": "^3.4.3",
    "react-scrollspy-nav": "^1.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

and I also created `main.scss` file to import my bootstrap of which I'm going to import to my `index.js` file just like it suggested in the [docs](https://blog.logrocket.com/trying-out-the-new-bootstrap-5-with-react/) I saw

and so I started testing it with things like `<button class="btn btn-danger">Test</button>` and it worked fine but when I start do tables like

```
      <table className="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>firstname</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
        <th>handle</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>doe</td>
        <td>@john</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>jane</td>
        <td>doe</td>
        <td>@jane</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it wont work at all am i doing something wrong or that's just how it is?

Comment: So I believe you have to either do something like this: import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; where your importing the boostrap css or you need to use one of their components. I would go here to set it up: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/